# how to pass query parameters from DRF serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

when we pass query params through a request to DRF, are query params passed through serializer ? or is there any way to pass them from serializer ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to pass them to the serializer. Query parameters from the request are handled within the view only. An example for filtering a returned queryset using a query parameter would be like:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response

@api_view(['GET'])
def product_list(request):
    qs = Product.objects.all()
    search = request.query_params.get('search')  # Get query parameter
    if search is not None:
        qs = qs.filter(title__icontains=search)
    serializer = ProductSerializer(qs, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass additional data when instantiating a serializer in the `context` argument:

```
def some_view(self, request):
    serializer = SomeSerializer(data=request.data, 
                                context={"qp": request.query_params.get("qp")})
```

The context will be accessible in any serializer field method like:

```
def get_some_field(self, instance):
    qp = self.context["qp"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameters do not pass throught a Serializer. You need to do it manually.

Here is the example of a DRF view which is generated throught a Serializer which accepts GET-query parameters and return the 200 Response only if query parameters are ok:

```py
from serializers import MySerializer
from rest_framework.viewsets import GenericViewSet
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import action

    
class MyView(GenericViewSet):

    @action(methods=["GET"], detail=False)
    def my_view_endpoint(self, request):
       serializer = MySerializer(data=request.query_params)
       serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
       return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK, data=serializer.data)
```